# Sites similar to SU where I can ask general questions?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I ask questions that aren’t programming questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions)

I wanted to know from where i can get answers to my general questions same as this site is for General Technical Questions based site, plz share such websites?

Comment: In general you should find a forum that is specific to the topic you are asking, otherwise you end up with places like Yahoo Answers.

Answer (score 7):

[Yahoo! Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/)

Comment: It's like SU with no rules and no rep.  The Wild West SuperUser, if you will.

Comment: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=Am8siuiqsDCYOQ7o8iEP.I3py6IX;_ylv=3?qid=20090911110421AAs1FhK was on the homepage. This is not a website people with IQs visit :(

Comment: [How is babby formed?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090817201337AA4Cxo3)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a few (in addition to the already-mentioned Yahoo! Answers):

- [AnswerBag](http://www.answerbag.com)
- [WikiAnswers](http://wiki.answers.com/)
- [AskVille](http://askville.amazon.com/Index.do)

Additionally, the people behind SuperUser.com are developing [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com/), a platform that anyone can license (for a fee) and create a specialized Q&A site of their own. 
They're currently beta-testing, there should be plenty of specialized SuperUser-esque sites in the coming weeks as development continues.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Mahalo Answers](http://www.mahalo.com/answers/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Ask metafilter](http://ask.metafilter.com/)